# Segmentation - Making Segments Sharper

Tags: clustering

I have a question.

We’ve done a study that looks at the youth’s attitudes towards “social issues” such as water, sanitation and public health. We then segmented the population using factor analysis (K-Means clustering) and arrived at four clusters.

Our client came had the following question –

1. The results have shown only some basic attitudinal archetypes without very sharp differences. Currently clustering has been done for ALL data, i.e. every respondent in the dataset falls into some cluster. Is there a way to sharpening the clusters/differences in these segments by looking at respondents that don’t fall within the centre/bulk of the normal distribution of the population, but rather those that fall in the extremes.

My thoughts on this are as follows;

Right now my clusters are based on ALL respondents, i.e. all 2048 respondents. My client wants to know if there is a way to make the differences between the segments sharper? I can think of one of 4 methods to do this;

1. Instead of using data of ALL respondents, I use a significantly smaller data-set consisting of only those people who are attitudinally amendable. In this case the clustering will have to be re-done on a reduced base? Please let me know if this correct? What would the approach be?
2. Currently ALL respondents are falling into the four clusters. I can remove respondents from these clusters who fall within the bulk of normal people and make the clusters sharper i.e. I can try and find extreme points within the clusters. Please let me know if this correct? What would the approach be?
   I want advice on how to do this? Someone suggested a regression, but would the regression be before/after the clustering?

Will be very grateful for any help/direction.

Comment: Could you please explain what a "sharp" difference is and what it might mean to "sharpen" a "segment," "cluster," or "difference"?

Comment: I think what we are being asked to do is to make each cluster more distinct from the other clusters. Although I may have found a solution - reducing the number of factors and doing a regression to find significant factors BEFORE doing the segmentation.

Comment: Since "cluster" is a generic term that could be described in many ways, it's not clear precisely what making them "more distinct" would actually amount to, nor what objective basis you might use to do this.  What is the purpose behind the idea of making clusters more distinct?  How will the clustering results be used?